# Parameter transfer with cin function

Tags: c++, methods, parameters, cin

I want that the user is able to enter the RGB colors one after one, I tried to keep the code simple as possible. The code below works, causes no errors, but I dont understand why its not in the correct order R > G > B, the first entered value is in this case the blue color, which is not wanted.

```
cout << "Enter successively red-, green, blue-part: " << endl;
c.setColor(readColor(cin), readColor(cin), readColor(cin));
```

**setColor is defined:**

```
void RGB_Color::setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
    this->red = red;
    this->green = green;
    this->blue = blue;
```

**readColor function:**

```
int readColor(istream &stream)
{
    int i;
    stream >> i;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: oh, sorry. Thanks for reffering.

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified, so those `readColor` calls could occur in any order. A simple fix is to make the order explicit:

```
int r,g,b;
std::cin >> r >> g >> b;
c.setColor(r,g,b);
```

Another possibility would be to overload `operator>>` for `RGB_Color` (making it a `friend` if the member data is private):

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, RGB_Color& color) {
    is >> color.red >> color.green >> color.blue;
    return is;
}
```